# How do I combine bands in a tiff then convert to grayscale?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, color, geotiff-tiff

I have a large mosaic of tiffs in which I need to do the following: 
-Combine bands 4,3,2, for an infrared image then convert the image to grayscale without producing another dataset
-This is easy on QGIS but I need to execute this on ArcGIS 10.1

Is there a way to render the image like on QGIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct method, but there are two ways of achieving this.

First, it can be done using the image analysis window (Windows > Image analysis). Select your image, then apply your function (fct button in "Processing") on it. To select a function (in your case, "composite band" and/or " grayscale"), right-click on the identity function and select "insert"). Mainly interesting if you have many functions to apply.

[image]

On the image, you see my "on the fly" grayscale image from a multispectral image.

The other method consists in computing your grayscale image (band1 + band 2+ band3)/3 in raster calculator with an [in memory](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000005s000000) output. No need to create a composite raster before.

> in_memory/grayscale

As a remark, slightly out of ArcGIS, ArcGIS supports the vrt format. So you could also create a vrt and open it in ArcGIS.